# Hibernate restriction on a set

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to use a restriction on a field of Book class which is a java.util.Set. The Book class is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Book implements java.io.Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The book id. */
    private int bookId;


    /** The authors. */
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>(0);


    /**
     * Gets the book id.
     * 
     * @return the book id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Book_Id")
    public int getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the book id.
     * 
     * @param bookId
     *            the new book id
     */
    public void setBookId(int bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }




    /**
     * Gets the authors.
     * 
     * @return the authors
     */
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Book_Author", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Book_Id", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Author_Id", nullable = false) })
    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the authors.
     * 
     * @param authors
     *            the new authors
     */
    public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }



    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + bookId;
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        if (bookId != other.bookId) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have deleted some fields and their Getters and Setters in the above class.
In the persistence layer the code to retrieve books is as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                            .add( Projections.property("bookId"), "bookId")
                            .add( Projections.property("publisherName"), "publisherName")
                            .add( Projections.property("publishedYear"), "publishedYear")
                            .add( Projections.property("description"), "description")
                            .add( Projections.property("title"), "title")
                            .add( Projections.property("image"), "image")
                            .add( Projections.property("availability"), "availability")
                            .add( Projections.property("authors"))
                            .add( Projections.property("categories"))
                            ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Book.class));
            criteria.add(
                    Restrictions.conjunction().add(
                            Restrictions.like("availability", "AVAILABLE")))
                    .add(Restrictions
                            .disjunction()
                            .add(Restrictions.like("title", bookAttributesLike, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                            .add(Restrictions.like("authors.authorName",
                                    bookAttributesLike, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                            .add(Restrictions.like("categories.categoryName",
                                   bookAttributesLike, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
            result = criteria.list();
```

Now I authors is a Set and Author class has field authorName, authorId. I want to put restriction on this authorName. Similar is the case for category. 
So how can this be done? Also when I don't use projection the above restrictions work fine. So also whats the reason for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is root of your problem. However you should add alias to your criteria such as:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                    .createAlias("authors", "authors")...
```

Also categories should be aliased